C++ unordered_map thread safety when inserting indepentent keys
C++ Container thread safety guidelines at  http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container#Thread_safety
say

Different elements in the same container can be modified concurrently by different threads

So my question is, let us say I have an
unordered_map<MyKeyClass, MyValueClass> results and I have several threads running concurrently and populating this map upon completion with <unique_key, some_value>. It is guaranteed that each thread returns a unique MyKeyClass. Does that now mean that I can safely concurrently insert the values into results ?
If yes, then that answers my question.
If no, then how about I insert <key, empty_value> before spawning the threads and then there will be no concurrent insertions, just modifications of the values, which if I understand correctly should be ok ?


Does that now mean that I can safely concurrently insert the values into results ?

No. A std::unordered_map is not inherently thread safe. You cannot modify it from different threads without adding synchronization.
Modifying elements in a container can be done without modifying the container itself.

If no, then how about I insert <key, empty_value> before spawning the threads and then there will be no concurrent insertions, just modifications of the values, which if I understand correctly should be ok ?

Yes. The sentence you quote is about modifying elements in the container. It is not about inserting elements into a container. You cannot concurrently insert but modify elements.

Is the reason concurrent insertion of unique elements not being safe because of possible collision? Because I'd imagine if the elements had unique hash values then there shouldn't be an issue with concurrent insertion?
